Is there a way in Zeep to ignore the namespace provided in a WDSL?
With this WSDL: http://recette.jedeclare.com/webservices/wspid_spring/CommunicationV2Service/communicationV2.wsdl
When I try any of the types defined, I get "zeep.exceptions.LookupError: No type 'Type' in namespace http://experian.com/communicationV2/schemas." because the namespace does not exists (it returns a 404).
wsdl = 'http://recette.jedeclare.com/webservices/wspid_spring/CommunicationV2Service/communicationV2.wsdl'

client = Client(wsdl)

identification_type = client.get_type('ns0:Authentification')


will result in "zeep.exceptions.LookupError: No type 'Authentification' in namespace http://experian.com/communicationV2/schemas."
